# .append() method only appends half of the items

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var sitename = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";
var ajaxhot = document.getElementById("hotajax");
var ajaxpopular = document.getElementById("popularajax");
var ajaxtoday = document.getElementById("todayajax");
var ajaxcurrent = document.getElementById("partial-index");
var ajaxindex = document.getElementById("ajax-index");

function indexajaxfunc(ajaxbutton, getfrom) {
    ajaxbutton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var getnew = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        getnew.open("GET", sitename + getfrom);
        getnew.onload = function () {
            var newtitlespagestring = getnew.responseText;
            var newtitlespage = parser.parseFromString(newtitlespagestring, "text/html");
            var newtitles = newtitlespage.getElementById("content-body").children[1];
            ajaxcurrent.children[0].children[0].innerHTML = newtitlespage.getElementById("content-body").children[0].innerHTML;
            while (ajaxindex.hasChildNodes()) {
                ajaxindex.removeChild(ajaxindex.lastChild)
            }
            console.log(newtitles.childElementCount);
            for(i=0; i<newtitles.childElementCount; i++) {
                ajaxindex.append(newtitles.children[i])
            }
        };
        getnew.send();
    });
}

indexajaxfunc(ajaxhot, "titles/hot/");
indexajaxfunc(ajaxpopular, "titles/popular/");
indexajaxfunc(ajaxtoday, "titles/today/");
```

I'm trying to get the elements from the url and append it into ajaxindex yet I'm getting an unexpected result.

---> While statement removes all childs.

---> Console logs the new title count which is either 25(hot and today) or 4(popular)

---> Then the next statement should append all the titles to the ajaxindex but it only appends half of it, 13 of 25 titles or 2 of 4 titles.

If I modify the code a little bit and change it to

```
        for(i=0; i<newtitles.childElementCount; i++) {
            console.log(newtitles.children[i])
        }
```

It logs all the 25(or 4 if popular) of the titles from the new page but for some reason when I modify it to

```
        for(i=0; i<newtitles.childElementCount; i++) {
            console.log(newtitles.children[i]);
            ajaxindex.append(newtitles.children[i]
        }
```

it both appends and logs 13(or 2 if popular) new element.

I've tried replacing the for loop's count manually with i<25 still it only appends 13 and in plain text ads "undefined" to the end of the html.

My question is both, why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: It has 25 ( and 25 ), can you please tell me which ) is missing?

Comment: In the last code snippet.

Comment: Oh, that was me writing it on the fly, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DOM node can't be in two DOM trees at once. When you call `.append()` in your loop, it appends the node to the specified parent and *removes* it from its current parent. Thus, each time you increment `i` you are skipping over the next node.

Also note that `.append()` is an experimental feature not implemented in all browsers. Consider using `.appendChild()` instead.

There are a few ways you could fix this; one simple way would be to change your `for` loop to:

```
while( newtitles.firstChild ) {
    console.log( newtitles.firstChild );
    ajaxindex.appendChild( newtitles.firstChild );
}
```

It's also worth noting that you were missing a `var` or `let` in the `for` loop. That isn't an issue with the `while` loop above, of course.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I removed the i++ from the for loop and both for and while versions worked beautifully.

Comment: That's a very insightful experiment; nice work. Removing `i++` converts the `for` loop to be equivalent to the `while` loop I posted. `newtitles.firstChild` and `newtitles.children[0]` are the same thing, and each iteration of the loop removes that element from `newtitles`. In fact if you check the revision history of my answer, I first wrote it using `newtitles.children[0]` and then changed it to `newtitles.firstChild` for simplicity.